# NSKernAttributeName ruins the scrolling of UITextField for long strings

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitextfield

I set the NSKernAttributeName attribute for the `attributedString` of a `UITextField` to 9.5. When I type a long text that is longer than the width of the `UITextField`, I need to type 20-30 extra characters before the `UITextField` autoscrolls to the cursor. My font size is 23 while the minimum font size is set at 14 with Adjust to Fit enabled. I need the `UITextField` to scroll with the cursor as soon as the string is too long to fit the width of the `UITextField`.

When I set NSKernAttributeName value to 0.0, the scrolling seems to work fine.